# Why is LEGO kit name not on the box or booklet?

Tags: manufacturing, disney

Curious to know why LEGO set boxes and instruction booklets carry a number and age recommendation (Eg 7-12 41317), but not any marketing name (Sunshine Catamaran)?

To get the name, I need to visit an online store selling the kit to get the actual name of it. Not sure if this is just an Australian marketing practise but curious as to why this is so - I find it frustrating.

Answer (score 7):

Most-likely it has to do with localization.

If they printed the names of sets on instructions, they would have to print a different instruction booklet for each language the set name is translated into, in addition to translating the boxes (and possibly the stickers).

You will notice that instruction manuals are usually free of any written instructions, which would need to be translated, and instead opt for imagery when possible. If they do have substantial text, it is usually translated into a number of languages, like the game rules in the back of the manuals for the large Orient Expedition sets had.

[image: Orient Expedition game rules picture]

Of course, simple things like "Click" get a pass on translation.

[image: "Click" example]

Sets whose name would not change if localized sometimes have names printed on their instructions though.

[image: Tahu Nuva instructions]

Answer (score 3):

It's more complicated than that. In some markets boxes do carry the set's name. I just took a picture of two sets I have lying around unopened:
[image]

As you can see the elves set in front has the name on the box, while the Disney princesses set in the back doesn't.

I don't precisely remember where I bought those two sets (but it's not unlikely one was intended for sale abroad), but I suspect it has to do with what markets they were intended for. It's probably relatively expensive to have boxes printed with the danish name (I'm from Denmark) as they would basicaly only be usable in Denmark,while boxes with the english name are far more usable. But as you speak english in Australia, and you say you see boxes without names on them, that can't be all.

Comment: It's possible that the sets shipped for sale to Australia are also for other markets around the Pacific, which would include a number of non-English speaking countries.